# Помогите в кодом, при вводе не которых выражений, отсутствует результат

Tags: java, intellij-idea, калькулятор

Отправляю все в одном тексте, все классы создание отдельно.
Вопрос такой, в консольном калькуляторе при вводе некоторых выражений (Именно умножение: Например V * V включительно до римской V) все значения показывают результат, а по возрастанию чисел результат сумм не выводится, с чем это может быть связанно? Как это исправить, подскажите пожалуйста. Я совсем новичок и этот код скопирован, для разбора полётов.Ломаю голову, не могу ни к чему прийти.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            int result = 0;
            String outputStr = "";
            int op1, op2 = 0;

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            String input1 = scanner.next();
            String operator = scanner.next();
            String input2 = scanner.next();

            System.out.println("=");

            input1 = input1.toUpperCase();
            input2 = input2.toUpperCase();

            Accept validate = new Accept();

            if (validate.acceptInput(input1, input2, operator) == "roman") {
                ConvertRoman romanOp = new ConvertRoman();
                op1 = romanOp.romanToInt(input1);
                op2 = romanOp.romanToInt(input2);
                switch (operator) {
                    case "+": result = op1 + op2;
                        break;
                    case "-": result = op1 - op2;
                        break;
                    case "/": result = op1 / op2;
                        break;
                    case "*": result = op1 * op2;
                        break;
                }
                outputStr = romanOp.intToRoman(result);
            }
            else {
                op1 = Integer.valueOf(input1);
                op2 = Integer.valueOf(input2);
                switch (operator) {
                    case "+": result = op1 + op2;
                        break;
                    case "-": result = op1 - op2;
                        break;
                    case "/": result = op1 / op2;
                        break;
                    case "*": result = op1 * op2;
                        break;
                }
                outputStr = Integer.toString(result);
            }

            System.out.println(outputStr);

            scanner.close();
        }
    }
```

```
import java.util.*;

public class ConvertRoman {
    public int romanToInt(String input) {
        int result = 0;
        switch (input) {
            case "I":
                result = 1;
                break;

            case "II":
                result = 2;
                break;

            case "III":
                result = 3;
                break;
            case "IV":
                result = 4;
                break;
            case "V":
                result = 5;
                break;
            case "VI":
                result = 6;
                break;
            case "VII":
                result = 7;
                break;
            case "VIII":
                result = 8;
                break;
            case "IX":
                result = 9;
                break;
            case "X":
                result = 10;
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String intToRoman(int input) {
        String result = "";
        switch (input) {
            case 1:
                result = "I";
                break;
            case 2:
                result = "II";
                break;
            case 3:
                result = "III";
                break;
            case 4:
                result = "IV";
                break;
            case 5:
                result = "V";
                break;
            case 6:
                result = "VI";
                break;
            case 7:
                result = "VII";
                break;
            case 8:
                result = "VIII";
                break;
            case 9:
                result = "IX";
                break;
            case 10:
                result = "X";
                break;
            case 11:
                result = "XI";
                break;
            case 12:
                result = "XII";
                break;
            case 13:
                result = "XIII";
                break;
            case 14:
                result = "XIV";
                break;
            case 15:
                result = "XV";
                break;
            case 16:
                result = "XVI";
                break;
            case 17:
                result = "XVII";
                break;
            case 18:
                result = "XVIII";
                break;
            case 19:
                result = "XIX";
                break;
            case 20:
                result = "XX";
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
public class Accept {
    private boolean isRoman(String inputStr){
        return inputStr.matches("^I$|^II$|^III$|^IV$|^V$|^VI$|^VII$|^VIII$|^IX$|^X$");
    }

    private boolean isStringInt(String s)
    {
        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String acceptInput(String input1, String input2, String operator) {
        String result = "";
        if (isRoman(input1) ^ isRoman(input2)){
            throw new RuntimeException("Цифры разного счисления");
        }
        if (!isRoman(input1) && !isRoman(input2) && (!isStringInt(input1) || !isStringInt(input1))) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Римские цифры вне пределов или числа не целые");
        }

        int op1 = 0;
        int op2 = 0;

        if(isRoman(input1)) {
            ConvertRoman romanOp = new ConvertRoman();
            op1 = romanOp.romanToInt(input1);
            op2 = romanOp.romanToInt(input2);
        }
        else {
            op1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input1));
            op2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(input2));
        }

        if (((op1 < 1) || (op1 > 10)) || ((op2 < 1) || (op2 > 10))) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Операнды не в пределах");
        }

        if (!operator.matches("[-+*/]{1}")){
            throw new RuntimeException("Оператор не правильный");
        }

        if (isRoman(input1)) {
            result = "roman";
        }
        else {
            result = "decimal";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Текущая реализация метода `ConvertRoman#intToRoman` не поддерживает конвертацию из арабских цифр в римские для чисел больше 20.
Для того чтобы работало корректно можно расширить возможные значения оператора `switch`:

```
switch (input) {
    ...
    case 21:
        result = "XXI";
        break;
    ...
}
```

Либо уже переписать данный метод более универсально. Варианты написания универсального метода можете посмотреть, например, в соотвествующем обсуждении на английском языке [Converting Integers to Roman Numerals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967896/converting-integers-to-roman-numerals-java)